# Looking for an old sci-fi story highlighting racism using an ignorant Martian

Tags: story-identification

Looking for an old sci-fi story about a Martian brought to earth.  The Martian is barely intelligent and is the butt of many racist jokes, recycled to be pointed at him.  An African-American notes that he's glad that the Martian is now the bottom of the pecking order.

Comment: How old was this story? Was it a short story, part of an anthology or a novel? What language was it in? Any little detail might be helpful!

Comment: maybe a Twilight Zone episode

Answer (score 8):

["The Day the Martians Came"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57223) (aka "The Day After the Day the Martians Came"), a short story by [Frederik Pohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl). Here is the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_the_Day_the_Martians_Came) summary:

> **"The Day After the Day the Martians Came"** is a short story by [Frederik Pohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl) from [Harlan Ellison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlan_Ellison)'s [Dangerous Visions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangerous_Visions), which shows how humans can (and will) laugh at (and hate) any minority group. It centers on a group of reporters in a bar, shortly after humans have made first contact with Martians, who are passing the time by retelling 'dumb Polack' jokes as 'dumb Martian' jokes.
>
> *The Day After the Day the Martians Came* was adapted by [Marvel Comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Comics) in [Worlds Unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds_Unknown) #1, May, 1973 illustrated by [Ralph Reese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Reese). [See [The Bronze Age of Blogs](http://bronzeageofblogs.blogspot.com/2009/03/day-after-day-martians-came.html).]

The following exchange between the motel manager (Mr. Mandala) and the black bell captain (Ernest) comes at the end of the story (text copied from p. 127 of the [Ballantine Books June 1975 printing](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?254908) of [*The Best of Frederik Pohl*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38123)):

> "Know what I think, Ernest? Outside of the jokes, I don't think that six months from now anybody's going to remember there ever were such things as Martians. I don't believe their coming here is going to make a nickel's worth of difference to anybody."
>
> "Hate to disagree with you, Mr. Mandala," said Ernest mildly, "but I don't think so. Going to make a difference to some people. Going to make a *damn* big difference to me."